# Get Context in a Jetpack Compose Noncomposable function

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose

I want to insert some data into Firebase. for that, I have a non-composable function and in that function, I'd like to call Toast.makeText . . in the .addOnSuccessListener part.
However, there's no way for me to get the context that should be in the Toast.makeText statement

```
fun saveActivityToFB(
    answer: String,
    question: String,
    id: String
) {

    var db: DatabaseReference = Firebase.database.reference
    val ques = Question(answer, question)

    db.child("activity").child("test").child(id).setValue(ques)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("FB", "OK")

           //problems with context here!!
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Added to FB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("FB", "Not inserted into FB")
        }
}
```

I know that in order to display Toast from composable function, I should get context as:

`val context = LocalContext.current`

But have no idea how to get the context in this case.

Comment: If you want to display toast from `saveActivityToFB` itself, you can pass `Context` as another argument in this function.

Comment: Would you please be so kind and show your suggestion in code . . Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I got it as you suggested. I am having quite some problems with understanding Context . . . Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to call that function from a composable function, make it composable and access it via `LocalContext.current`. If you're calling it from a ViewModel, you can make it an `AndroidViewModel` and use the `ApplicationContext` instead. You shouldn't access a Context otherwise. Think about its name—"Context"—the circumstances that form the app state. Following this wavelength, it becomes easy to understand where you should access the Context: you can't just get it out of nowhere, you need to retrieve it from somewhere UI-related. Hence, try doing one the aforementioned methods. If none fit, please provide more information on where you're calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun Test(){
    val context = LocalContext.current // here no problem getting context
    var db: DatabaseReference = Firebase.database.reference
    db.child("activity").child("test").child(id).setValue(ques)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.d("FB", "OK")

       //use context from outside of the scope here
        Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Added to FB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
        Log.d("FB", "Not inserted into FB")
    }

}
```